# How to add sepa header this in XML via SQL or C#

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq-to-xml

How to add `sepa header` like this in `XML` via `SQL` or `C#`. Please help

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance">
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what a "sepa header" is, or what this has to do with SQL. Could you clarify your question please? It would also be very helpful if you could show what you've tried so far and what happens.

Comment: I wrote this code in SQL and with the help ROOT('Document'), ELEMENTS XSINIL;
i am getting this `<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance">` and I want this in header
`<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance">` 
@DaisyShipton

Comment: Sorry, it's still really unclear what you're trying to achieve, or what exact SQL you used (I suspect it's more than that). Please edit your question to be much clearer. I assume you actually want content as well - but you haven't told us anything about that. Personally I'd fetch the data from the database and construct the XML using LINQ to XML unless there's a very good reason not to, but with so little context it's hard to help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given up trying to get namespaces correct using the Net libraries.  I just parse the strings which always work and is simpler.  See code below :

```
            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Document xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance\" xmlns=\"urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02\"></Document>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
            XElement document = doc.Root;
```

Comment: Can you give me code further also please how can i add before `xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance">;`

Because i am newbie in this. @jdweng

Comment: Just reverse the order of the two namespaces in the string.  I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

Add `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` to your query, which sets the default xml namespace.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (                  
    DEFAULT 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02'
    )
```

Your query will look some like here below.
*Change the SELECT here below with your query.*

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (                  
    DEFAULT 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02'
    )  
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('Document'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

This will result in

```
<Document 
    xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      
    >
```

Comment: Thank you so much. but I am getting `<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02">'

I want 
`<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance">`

Is there any chance i can add XMLNAMESPACES before xmlns:xsi??? @pfx

Comment: That is not an option; anyway, the order of xml namespace declarations doesn't matter with xml.

Comment: Ok, not problem with order but which namespace i have given its repeating in approx every node can you tell me why is that and how can i remove that from child node. I want it on the top only. @pfx

Comment: Example : -
<Document 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02">
  <pain.001.001.02>
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02">checking</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02">2018-05-22T16:42:12.747</CreDtTm>
      <Authstn xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02">ILEV</Authstn>
      <NbOfTxs xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02">2</NbOfTxs>

Comment: Can you provide the full SQL statement and which version of SQL server you are on? The result at my side doesn't repeat the namespace.

Comment: --Create table XMLExporting(ID int identity(1,1),Name varchar(max),CreatedDate DateTime)
--insert into XMLExporting(name,CreatedDate)
--select 'Vishal',GetDate()

`;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02')
SELECT
    (SELECT name as 'MsgId',CreatedDate as 'CreDtTm','ILEV' as 'Authstn','1' as 'NbOfTxs','100' as 'CtrlSum',
   'ABC111111' As 'InitgPty/Id/OrgId/BkPtyId','HSBC Connect' as 'FwdgAgt/FinInstnId/PrtryId/Id'
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS 'GrpHdr'
FROM XMLExporting a(nolock)
FOR XML PATH('pain.001.001.02'), ROOT('Document'), ELEMENTS XSINIL;`

Comment: SQL Server 2014 and this is sample code i am running please check when you can. @pfx

Comment: `WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
    default 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02'    
    ) 
SELECT 
    name as 'GrpHdr/MsgId',
    CreatedDate as 'GrpHdr/CreDtTm',
    'ILEV' as 'GrpHdr/Authstn',
    '1' as 'GrpHdr/NbOfTxs',
    '100' as 'GrpHdr/CtrlSum', 
    'ABC111111' As 'GrpHdr/InitgPty/Id/OrgId/BkPtyId',
    'HSBC Connect' as 'GrpHdr/FwdgAgt/FinInstnId/PrtryId/Id'
FROM XMLExporting a(nolock) 
FOR XML PATH('pain.001.001.02'), ROOT('Document'), ELEMENTS XSINIL; `

Comment: `;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02') 
SELECT 
 (SELECT name as 'MsgId',CreatedDate as 'CreDtTm','ILEV' as 'Authstn','1' as 'NbOfTxs','100' as 'CtrlSum' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS 'GrpHdr'
 ,(SELECT name as 'PmtInfId','TRF' as 'PmtMtd','RTGS' as 'PmtTpInf/ClrChanl',
  (Select 'awd' as 'Nm' for xml path('Dbtr'), type) 
 for xml path('finID'), type) as 'PmtInf'
FROM XMLExporting a(nolock) 
FOR XML PATH('pain.001.001.02'), ROOT('Document'), ELEMENTS XSINIL;`

Please correct this previous one was not complete ex @pfx

Comment: please can you help me with last example which i have given

Comment: Sorry, I have too little experience with FOR XML queries. You will get better help if you open a new question about how to structure the xml. Didn’t the SQl in my last comment suffice?

Comment: well i am returning multiple select in one xml so i am also little bit confused but there are person which had done that but i am not getting any working example. @pfx